# smtp emails from cakephp vender returning: code: -1, response: lid mail address 'no-reply')]

Tags: email, cakephp, sendmail, pear

I have a cakephp site, built by another developer that sends emails with a vender ('smtpmail'), this has worked fine in the past but just migrated to another server and I am now getting the below error.

can't find anything like this on google, anyone else seen this?

```
authentication failure [SMTP: Invalid response code received from server (code: -1, response: lid mail address 'no-reply')]
```

I have set up all the needed configuration

```
private $host = "mail.example.com";
private $pure_host = "example.com";
private $port = "25";
private $username = "no-reply";
private $password = "****";
```

(example not the actual name of the site!)

Any suggestions much appreciated

Comment: Just found the answer, Not sure what the lid error was about, but this was resolved by putting the full username in (as in no-reply@example.com.

Feel free to remove this question if this was an obvious one!

Answer (score 0):

check if the private $username = "no-reply"; is an actual existing email account, maybe your server needs the full username to log in eg: private $username = "no-reply@urdomain.com"; make sure your password is also set.